# A problem with making a slider using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have these three points that I want each of them to get activated when clicked .it all goes well when I click forward, but it doesn't work in the other direction. I think the code is syntactically valid, but I can't detect which part of it is making it not working as expected.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=
        
        , initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dots">
            <div class="dot d-active back"></div>
            <div class="dot back"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
          </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
body{
      background-color:#777;
    }
    .dots {
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      width: 70px;
      height: 20px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      right: calc(50% - 35px);
      bottom: 20px;
    }
    .dots .dot {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid white;
    }
    .dots .d-active {
      background-color: #19c8fa;
      border: 1px solid #19c8fa;
    }
```

```
 $(".dot").click(function () {
    
      if ((!($(this).is(":first-child")))) {
       
        $(".dots .d-active").removeClass("d-active").next().addClass("d-active");
        
      }
       else if (!($(this).is(":last-child")) && ($(".dots .dot ").last().hasClass("d-active")) && ($(this).hasClass("back"))) {
        
      
        $(".dots .d-active").removeClass("d-active").prev().addClass("d-active");
    
       }
        
      
    
    
    })
```

Comment: *not working as expected* - please include what you *do* expect.  eg if you click on nth dot should that one be selected?   Or just the next one in line in the direction you click?  (eg if 1st is active, click on 3rd, then 2nd gets active, click on 3rd again, 3rd is active, click on 1st, 2nd is active etc.   What if the user clicks on the one that's already active?  Which way should it go?

Comment: just the next one in line in the direction I click, when I go forward and backward without skipping any point. I just want to know what mistake prevents it from performing that way ,although it seems logical to me.

Comment: @Ahmed Abd Alfttah Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example